# Cloth is not moving while Vertex Group is

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I've been trying to make the sling part of a trebuchet, and whenever I press play, I get this stretching effect instead of the cloth being pulled by the arm. I have vertex groups at the ends of the ropes, both of them having the cloth modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Here @Chris: https://blend-exchange.com/b/40obk8lw